# Why in Python Pandas, a float condition can delete objects in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, conditional-operator

### Dataset :

Hello. Please consider the below code based on the famous Iris dataset :

```
# Import : 
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd

# Dataset preview : 
dataset=load_iris()
df=pd.DataFrame(dataset['data'],columns=['Petal length','Petal Width','Sepal Length','Sepal Width'])
df['Species']=dataset['target']
df['Species']=df['Species'].apply(lambda x: dataset['target_names'][x])
df.head()

Output : 
Petal length Petal Width Sepal Length Sepal Width Species
0   5.1     3.5     1.4     0.2     setosa
1   4.9     3.0     1.4     0.2     setosa
2   4.7     3.2     1.3     0.2     setosa
3   4.6     3.1     1.5     0.2     setosa
4   5.0     3.6     1.4     0.2     setosa

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 150 entries, 0 to 149
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Petal length    150 non-null float64
Petal Width     150 non-null float64
Sepal Length    150 non-null float64
Sepal Width     150 non-null float64
Species         150 non-null object
```

### Problem occurence :

When I filter the dataframe based on numeric condition, the values of the non-numeric columns (here, `Species` which is an `object`) are deleted, see below :

```
col = ['Petal length','Petal Width','Sepal Length','Sepal Width']
df2 = df[df[col] < 5]
df2.info()
Output : 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 150 entries, 0 to 149
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Petal length    22 non-null float64
Petal Width     150 non-null float64
Sepal Length    104 non-null float64
Sepal Width     150 non-null float64
Species         0 non-null object

df2.head()
Output : 
    Petal length    Petal Width     Sepal Length    Sepal Width     Species
0   NaN     3.5     1.4     0.2     NaN
1   4.9     3.0     1.4     0.2     NaN
2   4.7     3.2     1.3     0.2     NaN
3   4.6     3.1     1.5     0.2     NaN
4   NaN     3.6     1.4     0.2     NaN
```

### Question :

As you can see `Species` column becomes `0 non-null object` and only `NaN`. I am sure I did something wrong in my condition but I can't understand what. 
**-> How can I make this condition and keep `Species` values not removed ?**

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Can you provide part of the data in a format that is convenient to use? The goal should be for anyone to be able to quickly copy/paste a few things and run your program. See: [mcve].

Comment: With that condition, are you trying to find the rows where **all** the values are below 5, or the ones with **any** value below 5.

Comment: The database I use is [openfoodfacts](https://world.openfoodfacts.org/data), it is a 2GB csv file, this is why I have simplified my question with iris. There is some columns as `sugar_100g` that I would like to filter based on condition with **all** the value below 5. In any case, I really thank you for your kind reply and help !

Comment: Did the method I posted work?

Comment: Yes thank you, it worked, but better than that, I really appretiate the detailled solving explanation you did. So, of course, I have marked your reply as the solution.

Comment: I’m glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, this is an easy fix. To understand what is going on, take a look at the output of `df[col] < 5`.

Here is an easy to run example which should demonstrate the problem:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col_1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col_2': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 'col_3': [19, 18, 2, 17, 20]})
print(f'df:\n{df}\n')

cols_to_filter = ['col_1', 'col_3']

mask_1 = df[cols_to_filter] < 3
print(f'mask_1:\n{mask_1}\n')

mask_2 = (df[cols_to_filter] < 3).any(axis='columns')
print(f'mask_2:\n{mask_2}\n')

res_df_1 = df[mask_1]
print(f'res_df_1:\n{res_df_1}\n')

res_df_2 = df[mask_2]
print(f'res_df_2:\n{res_df_2}\n')
```

Here are the various outputs of the program:

```
df:
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      1      5     19
1      2      4     18
2      3      3      2
3      4      2     17
4      5      1     20

mask_1:
   col_1  col_3
0   True  False
1   True  False
2  False   True
3  False  False
4  False  False

mask_2:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool

res_df_1:
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0    1.0    NaN    NaN
1    2.0    NaN    NaN
2    NaN    NaN    2.0
3    NaN    NaN    NaN
4    NaN    NaN    NaN

res_df_2:
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      1      5     19
1      2      4     18
2      3      3      2
```

To resolve this, you can use `df[(df[col] < 5).any(axis='columns')]` or `df[(df[col] < 5).all(axis='columns')]`, depending on what you're trying to do.

---

I couldn't resist tweaking your program. There are a few alternatives to that `.apply()`, this one should be the best.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

dataset = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset['data'], columns=['Petal length', 'Petal Width', 'Sepal Length', 'Sepal Width'])
df['Species'] = dataset['target_names'][dataset['target']]
```

Comment: where's the regex ;)

Comment: I approve of this plan

Comment: I MUST say thank you !!!! It works well ! Also, I really appreciate the detailed explanation about my issue. About my coding (for instance `.apply`), please understand that I have started to learn python without school, this is why my coding needs to be improved. Now I follow courses and I hope to become better !

Comment: @prog-amateur Of course, you don’t need to justify anything! We’re all constantly learning anyway, right? :)

Comment: @prog-amateur Although I did just notice that I never actually point out/explain the problem. I think I’ll edit my post to include that, it could be of use to someone.